# How to make a dropdown in a foreach of specific data

Tags: php, html, wordpress, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I need to push the results of an array into a bs dropdown how do i do that?

This is what i have

```
<?php
$translations = pll_the_languages(array('raw' => 1));

$lang_codes = array();

foreach ($translations as $lang => $info) {

    $lang_codes[$lang] = [
        'slug' => $info['slug'],
        'url' => $info['url'],
        'flag' => $info['flag']
    ];
}

?>
```

Result:

```
array(2) { 
 ["de"]=> array(3) { 
  ["slug"]=> string(2) "de" ["url"]=> string(34) "http://localhost/werk/Mol/de/haus/" ["flag"]=> string(66) "http://localhost/werk/Mol/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/de.png" 
 } 
 ["nl"]=> array(3) { 
  ["slug"]=> string(2) "nl" ["url"]=> string(26) "http://localhost/werk/Mol/" ["flag"]=> string(66) "http://localhost/werk/Mol/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/nl.png" 
 } 
}
```

How to push this result with the foreach into this bootstrap dropdown with the slug as the value and url as the link.

```
 <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it:

```php
echo '<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">';
foreach ( $lang_codes as $info ) {
    echo '<a class="dropdown-item" href="' . esc_url( $info['url'] ) . '">' .
        esc_html( $info['slug'] ) . '</a> ';
}
echo '</div>';
```

Or you might be looking for this (?), which simply loops through the `$translations` array without having to create the `$lang_codes` array:

```php
echo '<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">';
foreach ( $translations as $info ) {
    echo '<a class="dropdown-item" href="' . esc_url( $info['url'] ) . '">' .
        esc_html( $info['name'] ) . '</a> ';
}
echo '</div>';
```

And in the above code, I used `$info['name']` (i.e. the language name; see the [reference](https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/functions-reference/)) and not `$info['slug']`, but you can of course change it if you want.